# Deploying Rails app w/ Capistrano - No response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, passenger, capistrano

I'm having some trouble deploying a rails app to a VPS using capistrano. I'm running ubuntu 10.04, rvm, rails 3.2.2, and ruby 1.9.2, nginx, and passenger.

I tried deploying a test app with no problems, then tried doing everything with an actual app in pretty much the same way and now I've run into to trouble. I ran cap deploy:setup, cap deploy:check, cap deploy:cold without any errors.

Yet when I try to access the site, I get no response. I can't access static assets either. My nginx.conf file is pointing to the 'app_name/current/public'

The production.log doesn't give any hints either. It has pretty much nothing aside from some info about the asset compiling and migrations.

So I'm stumped. I thought I did everything the same way as I did with the test app when everything went smoothly but obviously I'm forgetting something. Let me know if there's any files I can post to help diagnose the problem. Appreciate the help!

my deploy.rb:

```
# RVM

$:.unshift(File.expand_path('./lib', ENV['rvm_path']))
require "rvm/capistrano"
set :rvm_ruby_string, 'default'
set :rvm_type, :user

# Bundler

require "bundler/capistrano"

# General

set :application, "my_app"
set :user, "deploy_user"

set :deploy_to, "/home/#{user}/#{application}"
set :deploy_via, :copy

set :use_sudo, false

set :normalize_asset_timestamps, false

# Git

set :scm, :git
set :repository,  "~/#{application}/.git"
set :branch, "master"

# VPS

role :web, "app_name.com"
role :app, "app_name.com"
role :db,  "app_name.com", :primary => true

# Passenger

namespace :deploy do
 task :start do ; end
 task :stop do ; end
 task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
   run "#{try_sudo} touch #{File.join(current_path,'tmp','restart.txt')}"
 end
end
```

**EDIT 1**
nginx access.log shows lots of these:

```
[01/Jun/2012:11:23:11 -0400] "-" 400 0 "-" "-"
```

and error.log has these:

```
cache: [GET /] miss
```

**EDIT 2:** Not sure why but I realized I can access the assets in my app's public folder. What does it mean!?

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured Nginx correctly? The virtual host's root must point to your Ruby on Rails application's public folder. The documentation for using [Nginx with Phusion passenger](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html) may help. Try to examine the Nginx log files, `access.log` and `error.log`, probably they can be found in `/var/log/nginx`.

Comment: The virtual host root is definitely pointing to the app's public root. I can easily switch app_name to the test app I deployed and it works fine, which is why this is so confusing.

Comment: The nginx logs don't reveal a whole lot either. I'll add them in my original post.